# Is it When or where in this sentence?

Tags: when, where

We all have a moment in our life **where** something happens and that change the course of our life.

Comment: "A moment **when**... and that **changes**" etc.

Comment: "where" is fine.  When we think of life as a journey, then "where" evokes that sense of traveling along through life and so makes sense.  Nevertheless it's a somewhat idiosyncratic usage.

Answer (score 2):

As I'm sure everyone here is aware, Einstein told us that we're living in a four-dimensional, smooth, connected Lorentzian manifold called *spacetime*, a combination of three dimensions of what we perceive as volumes of space and one dimension of what we perceive as unidirectional time. Our perceptions lead us to consider a moment as a point in time and a place as a point in space. And the Ngram viewer backs this up: writers prefer *moment when* to *moment where* by about thirty to one.

But English does accommodate the Einsteinian notion of a moment as a place in a metaphorical sense, perhaps involving abstractions such as emotions and personal relationships. Here is an excerpt from [*Temporality in Life As Seen Through Literature*](https://books.google.com/books?id=oOSg9tWSomEC&pg=PA166&dq=%22moment%20where%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXusPF_ZjSAhVM2IMKHSdGAKE4ChDoAQgfMAE#v=onepage&q=%22moment%20where%22&f=false) about the work of Virginia Woolf:

> Woolf also refers to moments of pain, whether it is the **moment where** the presence of someone does not mean anything for us, to that **moment where** it is suffering to recall the inadequate character of human relations....

(internal references removed)

Comment: +1.  As for smooth, are you ignoring gravity?

Comment: @ab2 Smooth in this context means infinitely differentiable. I find that one ignores gravity at one's peril.

Answer (score 0):

"We all have a moment **when** something happens..." is correct because *moment* is a point in time, and *when* describes a point in time.

*Where* would describe a location, "We all have a place *where* we go..."